# Any tool to change words position in a text?

Tags: nlp, text-processing

I'm looking for a tool that can change words position in a text. It's something like an article spinner, but without changing the words to synonymous.

An example:

Original text:

> I love eating apples and drinking orange juice, it's delicious.

Shuffled text:

> It's delicious, I love drinking orange juice and eating apples.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking a look at the python Natural Language Toolkit, [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/), you will need to install [python](http://python.org) first if your platform doesn't come with it, i.e. MS-Windows but it is available for most platforms.

The advantage is that rather than simply splitting the sentence into words and shuffling them - hoping for a meaningful result - *which you can do in about 3 lines of python* you will be able to parse a sentence and reorder retaining the meaning.

- Free
- Lots of examples & a book or two
- You will learn a lot about language structure
- You shouldn't have to change it t get results for different sentences

Answer (score 0):

From the command line available in your Operating System, you can use some tool that deals with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (also called *regex* or *regexp*) like, for example, `sed`, which is available at least in Linux, Mac OS X, and the BSDs:

```
$ echo "I love eating apples and drinking orange juice, it's delicious." |
  sed -r 's/(.*), (.*)\./\u\2, \1./'
It's delicious, I love eating apples and drinking orange juice.
```

The problem with this approach is that the regular expression is not grammatically intelligent by itself, you have to set the rules. But once you grasp basic *regex* rules, which is not difficult if you have a bit of patience, you can expand it to your heart's desire.

In this particular example, we use `echo` to output to sentence, and then call `sed` to process the output from echo:

- `'s/foo/bar/'` replaces *foo* with *bar* in the sentence.
- `.` matches any character.
- `*` matches the previous character (`.`) any number of times.
- To match an actual dot, we need to escape it with a back slash (`\.`).
- The first enclosed match `(.*)` becomes `\1` for our later use, the second `\2`.
- `\u` tells sed to set to uppercase the first character of `\2`.

sed can also take the input from a text file, like this:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*), (.*)./\u\2, \1./' FILENAME.txt
It's delicious, I love eating apples and drinking orange juice.
It's delicious, I love drinking kool-aid and eating french fries.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will only work if a) the parts to be swapped are separated by a comma & b) the first word should remain capitalised when moved after the comma, i.e. it is I.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Yes, although it should be easy for him to  get started, all rules will have to be set by hand. I upvoted your answer.